# How to edit a form with a checkbox and reflect changes on the database end

Tags: php, mysql

Note: 1 is for checked and 0 for not checked

```
<input type='checkbox' name='payed' value='".$row['payed']."' /> //checkbox on form
```

code snippet that checks data received from form

```
if (isset($_POST['payed'])) 
{
    $sug_query = "Update invoices SET payed = 1, WHERE id = $id"; 
    $db->exec($sug_query);
}
```

Comment: You should be using the `checked` attribute rather than `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the name of the checkbox exists as a POST variable:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])) {
    //Checkbox was checked and you should update the column in question.
} else{
    //Checkbox unticked. Set column to 0.
}
```

Or, using a ternary operator:

```
$val = isset($_POST['checkbox_name']) ? 1 : 0;
$sug_query = "Update invoices SET payed = $val WHERE id = $id"; 
$db->exec($sug_query);
```